# Barrating is not a function

Tags: javascript, function

i have a file where i call functions collectively. This file contains the following code. i get error on non-library(jquery.barrating.min.js) pages running this code.
error i got "barrating is not a function error".

how can i get the code to run if only this function exists?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#example').barrating({
    theme: 'fontawesome-stars'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run this code only if this function exists, you can test its presence in the jQuery prototype:

```
if (jQuery.prototype.barrating) {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should check for jQuery too just to be extra sure